# Performance of graph databases

Tags: neo4j, arangodb

Is there any size limitation in database in Neo4j and Arango db? I'm using python. Which one is more consistent?

Comment: What is your use case? Do you have a specific data set size in mind?

Comment: For social media post concept

Comment: For an example of a social media project, you might want to take a look at Max de Marzi's multi-part series on [creating a Twitter clone on Neo4j](https://maxdemarzi.com/2017/03/30/building-a-twitter-clone-with-neo4j-part-one/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find both are suitable for a concept project. The key difference you will notice though is that ArangoDB is a multi-model database, so it can store normal NoSQL document collections and key/values as well as normal graph data. Neo4j focuses just on the graph data. Typically any application that stores/reads graph data will need to also deal with flat document collections, and if you use Neo4j you'll need to implement another technology to do that, but with ArangoDB it's there for you. Both are consistent, size limitation is only hardware. Good luck with your concept.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.